# Maintaining sync realm between app screens

Tags: react-native, realm

After user login - what is the best practice to access a synced realm in all my app screens (I use react-navigation)?

Should I pass realm reference to the next screen via props ?
I have many screens so this seems not right to me

Thank you

Yuval

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HOC(Higher Order Component) to pass on your realm instance. 
Maybe, a package like [react-native-realm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-realm) can help you.

Comment: Thank you but I fail to understand how to implement it.Do I need to wrap every screen ?  Its also important to note that this is a sync realm and not local one so if I import it in every screen I actually duplicate its instances .

Comment: HOC's are only wrapped to the Root Component. As long as you are performing all operations on the same instance, this will hold good.
One more way would be to use Redux or Mobx, where your data layer handles the queries, and thus, all the data from Realm is available to all the components you connect your data layer to